# Как можно сделать чтобы работала форма GET в форме POST?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста может есть какой способ чтобы форма работала корректно? мне необходимо отправить get запрос из формы post. Из за того что форма в форме formaction не корректно работает. Проект на Laravel

Вообщем вот код

```html
<form method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="profile-advert__button-control">
        <input class="js-selected-checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="push"/>
        <button type="submit" formaction="{{ route('profile.publish_selected') }}">Опубликовать выбранные</button>
    </div>
    @if (session('error'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ session('error') }}
        </div>
    @endif
    @foreach ($adverts as $advert)
        <div class="profile-advert__item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span>№ {{ $advert->id }}</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" data-selected="check" name="{{ $loop->index }}" value="{{ $advert->id }}"/>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>                
                <div class="col-2">
                    <ul class="profile-advert-container__number">
                        <li>
                            <button type="submit" formaction="{{ route('profile.publish', $advert) }}">Опубликовать</button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <form action="{{ route('advert.edit', $advert) }}" method="GET">
                                <button type="submit" formaction="">Редактировать</button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button type="submit" formaction="{{ route('profile.close', $advert) }}">Завершить</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    @endforeach
</form>
```

Comment: `<button type="submit" formaction="{{ route('advert.edit', $advert) }}" formmethod="GET">Редактировать</button>`. Тег `form` нельзя вкладывать в `form` – удалите, оставив только кнопку с необходимыми атрибутами.

Comment: спасибо! не знал про formmethod то что нужно

Comment: @РустамГимранов а как то можно сделать чтобы токен теперь не передавался? http://i.imgur.com/LUhx3nU.png

Comment: Токен всегда нужно передавать. Уточните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя отправить GET запрос в POST, но вы можете передать в URL адресе аргмуенты GET запроса, это будет работать. Я не совсем понял зачем вам это, если я правильно понимаю, вы хотите внутри формы создать кнопку, например, редактирования и отправлять такую форму на специальную страницу для редактирования передав параметром ID аргмуента.

Вам нет необходимости создавать целую форму для этого, достаточно создать ссылку на адрес и передать параметры в URL.

```html
<a href="{{ route('advert.edit', $advert) }}"></a>
<!-- Не уверен что это сработает. Сработает когда получится что-то вроде: -->
<a href="/advert/edit?id=15"></a>
<!-- Ну или так, но это уже будет не GET параметр, как вы его получите зависит от Вашего фреймворка -->
<a href="/advert/edit/15"></a>
```

Comment: спасибо!!! буду иметь в виду данный вариант тоже